# Change Twitter login screen design

Tags: android, twitter, authentication

Ok... I have started to use Twitter Login in my app and i have noticed that it is pretty easy to implement it but there is not many tutorials about it. I have noticed that by default login page looks like this:
[image]

And i don't really like the way how it looks. I have made a little research and i found that application Vine has created their own login screen design like this one:
[image]

My question is how can i create my own LogIn screen design but steel i would be using Twitter login api.?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Also how do I make the string be `CouchPotatoApp` instead of a long package name?

Comment: Nvm I see that I can customize the string by logging into Fabric and changing the application name. But did you ever figure out a way to customze the login screen?